# Select with as doesn't change name of the column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and I am practising basic SQL commands.

I have two different databases (made by external company) – in both I tried:

```
Select column_name as Alias_Word
From
`Table_Name`
```

In one db `as` works without problem – column changed name but in second db not.

There is still name of db column.

Can it be possible, that `as` involved in Select doesnt change column name (in view)?

real select is:

```
select lza_zaehler as counter
from
`LZA_LAUFZAEHLER`
```

Comment: and tell us what databases you use (SQL-Server, Oracle, Access, H2, whatever...)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: What is the error you get, or what isn't working?

Comment: without error  - but there ist still same columns name

Comment: I just thought, counter could be a reserved word, so I tried it in phpMyAdmin. There renaming a column to 'counter' works. So please explain, where do you see that the name of your result is not changed?

Comment: I see column name - lza_zaehler without change. i use another word e.g. dog (instead of counter ). but there is still  lza_zaehler

Comment: Which version of MySQL do you use?